# How to access the variables content outside a post onSuccess answer using several frameworks?

Tags: android

I'm making a post to a webapi and I'm able to receive the answer.

I want to pick the answers and put them in a listview, and this is the problem: When manipulating the variables inside the response of each framework, I'm able to see the values and assign to variables declared global but the listview is always empty and crashes the app.

I already tried with Ion, Volley and Fast Networking. In all of them I'm able to retrieve the answer to the post, but not able to put the answer in the listview.

Below is the code where everything happens. For this issue I'm using Ion, but I can use any of the ones I previously stated. As long as I'm able to put this to work.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = null;
ArrayList<String> responseArray = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private ListView results;

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == NEW_ALARM && data != null) {
        if (data.hasExtra(this.Activity2.NEW_SEARCH) && data.getExtras().getBoolean(this.Activity2.NEW_SEARCH, false)) {

            dataReceived = true;
            searchFilter = (MyClass) data.getSerializableExtra("searchParams");

            Ion.with(this)
                    .load(Utils.POST_SEARCH_URL)
                    .setBodyParameter("type", searchFilter.type)
                    .setBodyParameter("language", searchFilter.language)
                    .setBodyParameter("location", searchFilter.location)
                    .setBodyParameter("country", searchFilter.country)
                    .asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String response) {
                            try {
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    responseArray.add(object.get("Name").toString());
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException j) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                j.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, responseArray);
        results.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

What can I do to achieve this?

02-14 20:15:22.152 5252-5331/pt.uteslab.findmyguide W/IonConscrypt: Conscrypt initialization failed.
                                                                    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/security/ProviderInstaller;
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:58)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:75)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.getSocket(ConscryptMiddleware.java:103)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.executeAffinity(AsyncHttpClient.java:301)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.access$100(AsyncHttpClient.java:51)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$1.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:190)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:740)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:758)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:658)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:44)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$14.run(AsyncServer.java:600)
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/pt.uteslab.findmyguide-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:58) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.initialize(ConscryptMiddleware.java:75) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.ion.conscrypt.ConscryptMiddleware.getSocket(ConscryptMiddleware.java:103) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.executeAffinity(AsyncHttpClient.java:301) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient.access$100(AsyncHttpClient.java:51) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.http.AsyncHttpClient$1.run(AsyncHttpClient.java:190) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.lockAndRunQueue(AsyncServer.java:740) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.runLoop(AsyncServer.java:758) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.run(AsyncServer.java:658) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer.access$800(AsyncServer.java:44) 
                                                                        at com.koushikdutta.async.AsyncServer$14.run(AsyncServer.java:600) 
                                                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller
                                                                        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                ... 12 more
                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
02-14 20:15:22.399 5252-5252/pt.uteslab.findmyguide D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-14 20:15:22.400 5252-5252/pt.uteslab.findmyguide E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: pt.uteslab.findmyguide, PID: 5252
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to destroy activity {pt.uteslab.findmyguide/pt.uteslab.findmyguide.GuideSearchActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void pt.uteslab.findmyguide.LocationTrack.stopListener()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3849)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3867)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:154)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5435)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void pt.uteslab.findmyguide.LocationTrack.stopListener()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at pt.uteslab.findmyguide.GuideSearchActivity.onDestroy(GuideSearchActivity.java:811)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:6456)
                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1143)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3836)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:3867) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1402) 
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5435) 
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
02-14 20:15:25.983 5252-5252/pt.uteslab.findmyguide I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5252 SIG: 9

Comment: Please post the log-cat by editing question.

Comment: How am I able to retrieve the log-cat?

Comment: Call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after the `for` loop in `onCompleted()`.

Comment: Calling the adapter didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input regarding the logcat. It was very helpful. After analyzing the log, I verified that there was a variable outside the scope of this code that was not being used nor initialized causing all this mess.
Thanks for your inputs.